# Cut a plane with a mesh in Blender

Tags: 3d, blender

I'm trying to generate a plane to use as a navmesh for pathing in Unity with Blender. I've created a simple map in Blender, and need to use the walls of this map to cut equivalent holes in a plane in areas that should not allow pathing. 
I've tried using the boolean-difference modifier but I seem to end up with strange 3d shapes which include some of the walls rather than the flat plane with holes that I'm looking for.

Is there another way to use meshes to subtract from other meshes, or should I be doing something differently when using the boolean modifier?

Answer (score 1):

Booleans don't work very with planes. Try a very very thin cube. Also, make sure you change the 'operation' button until you find the right one. Hope I helped :D